# VNC Server on Centos 6

Tags: centos-6

I'm having a problems with my VNC server on my linux VPS:
I want to connect but when I connect I get a black screen instead of the gnome desktop (I did install this).
This is the log file I get:

Xvnc TigerVNC 1.0.90 - built Dec  8 2011 01:43:50
Copyright © 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
Copyright © 2000-2006 Constantin Kaplinsky
Copyright © 2004-2009 Peter Astrand for Cendio AB
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11004000, The X.Org Foundation

Mon Feb 18 00:36:22 2013
vncext:      VNC extension running!
vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
expected keysym, got XF86TouchpadOn: line 120 of inet
expected keysym, got XF86TouchpadOff: line 121 of inet
/root/.vnc/xstartup: line 5: /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc: No such file or directory
/root/.vnc/xstartup: line 5: exec: /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc: cannot execute: No such file or directory

This is the xstartup I currently use...

## !/bin/sh

## Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:

unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
startx &

Any help please? :S

Answer (score 0):

Where is your xstartup? Also could you either pastebin it or format it properly, it's unreadable.

From the errors, this file is missing: /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc